# Accessing event object from ng-click inside of ng-repeat oddity

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqlite

http://jsfiddle.net/5mbdgau1/3/

In my fiddle example, I access the event object that is passed in via an `ng-click`.  It works fine although when accessing it in handling the promise from "OtherService" it is suddenly not there?  What is going on here?

Using jQuery works, so this has something to do with Angular jQlite I presume. Also, it breaks inside of `ng-repeat`, without that it works. I would like to know why the event object seems to disappear.  Thanks.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('TestController', function(TestService) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.foo = TestService;
  vm.items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
});

myApp.service('OtherService', function($http) {
  return $http.get('https://httpbin.org/get').then(function() {});
});

myApp.service('TestService', function(OtherService) {
  return function(evt) {
    var myText = evt.currentTarget.textContent;
    evt.currentTarget.textContent = "Bar";
    OtherService.then(function() {
      console.log(evt);
      evt.currentTarget.textContent =  myText + myText;
    });
  }
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
      <div ng-click="vm.foo(item, $event)">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the arguments from `ng-click` in the wrong order. Change `ng-click` from

```
<div ng-click="vm.foo(item, $event)">{{item}}</div>
```

to

```
<div ng-click="vm.foo($event, item)">{{item}}</div>
```

Your `TestService` function first expects an event object.

```js
// Code goes here
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('TestController', function(TestService) {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.foo = TestService;
  vm.items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
});

myApp.service('OtherService', function($http) {
  return $http.get('https://httpbin.org/get').then(function() {});
});

myApp.service('TestService', function(OtherService) {
  return function(item, evt) {
  console.log(evt, item)
    var myText = evt.currentTarget.textContent;
    evt.currentTarget.textContent = "Bar";
    OtherService.then(function() {
      console.log(evt);
      evt.currentTarget.textContent =  myText + myText;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
      <div ng-click="vm.foo(item, $event)">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: damn, that was a typo.  trying to reproduce a bug from a project.